# Strings in pandas series in list

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series where I would like to check if any string exists in a list. For example:

```
Series A:
A, B
A, B, C
E, D, F

List = ['A', 'B']
```

I would like to return is any element of List is in Series A, something like:

```
True
True
False
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your series consists of strings, you can use `set.intersection` (`&`):

```
L = ['A', 'B']

s = pd.Series(['A, B', 'A, B, C', 'E, D, F'])

res = s.str.split(', ').map(set) & set(L)

print(res)

0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
s.agg(lambda k: np.isin(k, List).any())

0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

This filter should give you a T/F vector: `A.apply(lambda _: _ in List)`

Also, you mention `Series` but that looks like you're referring to a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `issubset`

```
s.str.split(', ').apply(lambda x : {'A','B'}.issubset(tuple(x)))
Out[615]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Hmm, I read the question as needing [negative of] `isdisjoint`: "any" element of List is in series A..

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and `join` the list with `|` to look for any of the element of the list such as:

```
print (s.str.contains('|'.join(L))) #with @jpp definition of variable s and L
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```